# Problem in solving a question related to rank of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

**The question is** :

If $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix then show that $rank\ (A^{2}) - rank\ (A^{3}) \leq rank\ (A) - rank\ (A^{2})$.

I only manage to prove that $rank\ (A^{2}) - rank\ (A^{3}) \leq n - rank\ (A^{2})$ by Sylvester's inequality.But this is not well enough.So please help me to proceed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please give me a hint.Then I will definitely retry it.

Comment: Hint: Use the relation $$\operatorname{rank}(AB) = \operatorname{rank}(B) + \operatorname{dim}\left(\operatorname{kernel}(A) \cap \operatorname{range}(B)\right)$$ for suitable values of $B$.

Comment: I think @ArinChaudhury $rank\ (AB) = rank\ (B) - \dim (ker (A) \cap range (B))$.Isn't it?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T_A$ denote the transformation $T_A(x) = Ax$, and let $T|_V$ denote the restriction of the operator $T$ to the (invariant) subspace $V$.

Note (using the rank nullity theorem) that 
$$
rk(A) - rk(A^2) = \dim(im(T_A)) - rk(T_A|_{im(A)}) = nul(T_A|_{im(A)})
$$
Similarly, $rk(A^2) - rk(A^3) = nul(T_A|_{im(A^2)}$).  Now, it suffices to note that $\ker(T_A|_{im(A^2)}) \subset \ker(T_A|_{im(A)})$ since $im(T_A^2) \subset im(T_A)$.

---

Note that
$$
im(T_A^2) = \{A^2y : y \in \Bbb R^n\}\\
im(T_A|_{im(A)})=
\{Ax:x \in im(A)\} = 
\{Ax: x = Ay; y \in \Bbb R^n\}\\
= \{A^2 y: y \in \Bbb R^n\} \qquad \qquad \qquad \; 
$$

Comment: Sorry @Om I fail to understand the case $rk\ (A) - rk\ (A^{2}) = \dim (im\ A) - rk(T|_{im\ A})$.Please help me.

Comment: Be more specific; what is it that you don't understand?  Do you understand that $rk(A) = \dim(im(T_A))$?  That $im(T_A^2) = im(T_A|_{im(A)}$?

Comment: Actually @Om I don't understand the fact that $im\ (A^{2}) = im\ (T_{A}|_{im\ (A)})$.

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Very nice answer.